# Is it correct to say “I like someone as [a role]”?

Tags: prepositions

I would like ask, if I want to say I like someone to play a role, can I say “I like you as [the role]?”

Another example, “I like Kate as Snow White.” Does this sentence expressing I like Kate to play the role Snow White correctly?

Comment: This would benefit from a more concrete example.

Comment: It would be more common to use the conditional "would like" as you are talking about a propsed future production. The most common form would be variants of "I'd like you to play Feste" or "I'd like Kate as Snow White"

Comment: I like Kate as Snow White sounds like regular speech. In detective shows, they say "I like her for the murder," meaning she fits the role of the killer.

Comment: Or "I like Kate's portrayal of Snow White".

Comment: "I liked Cary Grant as the Rear Admiral" - online review of _Operation Petticoat_ and "I liked Cary Grant as Lou Gehrig, but I bet if I went back and saw it today I'd hate it." - Washington Post chat page

Comment: I think "for" would be more common in this context. "as" would be used when reviewing a performance, rather than casting.